# How to collapse in the bootstrap nav from right side?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is the following CSS code which I am adding in the stylesheet to collapse in the bootstrap  nav  form the right side of the webpage. But it's not working out. Please help me if someone know how to do it.

```
.collapsing{   
    position: relative !important;
    height: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    -webkit-transition: width .35s ease !important;
    -o-transition: width .35s ease !important;
    transition: width .35s ease !important;
}

.collapse{
    width:0 !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    right:0 !important;
    display: block;
}

.collapse.in{
    height:initial !important;
    width:100% !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;

}
```

Comment: Please provide HTML code too, Or set the jsfiddle to better understanding of issue here.

Comment: HTML code is same as in Bootstrap navigation, I am just tweaking CSS.

Comment: fiddle or something? without knowing that have your tried bootstrap ``pull-right``?